# Change the number of processes to spawn depending on the CPU usage in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-3.4

I want to change the number of processes to spawn depending on the CPU usage in python. 
Suppose the CPU in my laptop comes with 8 cores and currently 3 cores are fully used, which means maximum of 5 cores are available. Then I want my python program to spawn 5 processes on runtime.
Is there any way to achieve this in Python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the number of cores using

```
import multiprocessing
cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
```

and to get the current load average,

```
import os
loadavg = os.getloadavg()[0]
```

You can use these to determine your number of spawned processes.